# Using PHP to connect to MySQL: ERROR?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried running the following code: (http://localhost/read.php)

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE testphp",$link))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in                                    
C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheSoftware Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\read.php 
on line 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at you `phpinfo()`. Most likely mysql extensions is not there.

And while you are at it, you could just drop the ancient `mysql_*` way ow doing thing and learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements. It's an abstraction API for database connection and interaction.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand now. Investigating how to add the MySQL extension. Do not see anything in the phpinfo() that MySQL is active.

Answer (score 0):

your mysql-extension for php is not loaded! check that in your php.ini.

Comment: ah, yes...I think I know what the problem is now!? Will let you know if I fix it. Thanks.